# how can i update a specific row(patient)?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("dentalclinic") or die(mysql_error());

    if (isset($_POST['update'])){
    $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE appointment SET appointmentstatusid='$_POST[appointmentstatusid]'";
    mysql_query($UpdateQuery);
    };

    $sql = "SELECT * from appointment a join appointmentstatus s on (a.appointmentstatusid=s.appointmentstatusid) join patient p on (a.patientid=p.patientid)";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th>FIRST NAME</th>
    <th>LAST NAME</th>
    <th>APPOINTMENT STATUS</th>
    <th>UPDATE</th>
    </tr>";

    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<form action=editstatus.php method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=firstname value=".$record['firstname']."></td>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=lastname value=".$record['lastname']."></td>";
    echo "<td>";
    $query2 = "SELECT * from appointmentstatus"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query2);
    echo "<select name=appointmentstatusid>"; 
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value=".$line['appointmentstatusid'].">"; 
    echo $line['appointmentstatus'];
    echo "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>"."<input type=submit name=update value=update"."></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
    }       
echo "</table>"
?>
```

every time i update appointmentstatusid of patient1, it affects the appointmentstatus of other patients(patient2,patient3...). i tried adding the code `WHERE appointmentstatusid='$_POST[appointmentstatusid]'` on the update but when i do, it wont update anymore.

Comment: try $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE appointment SET appointmentstatusid='{$_POST['appointmentstatusid']}'";

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore because they are deprecared in the current versions of PHP. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: @SyedQarib the result is the same. it updates everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a specific record, your query should have a WHERE clause specifying what to update

```
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE appointment SET appointmentstatusid='$_POST[appointmentstatusid]' WHERE `appointmentid` = 1";
```

Please Note: passing the $_POST[appointmentstatusid] variable directly from $_POST can make your code vulnerable for sql injections. try

```
$appointmentstatusid = (int) mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[appointmentstatusid]); 
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE appointment SET appointmentstatusid='".appointmentstatusid ."' WHERE `appointmentid` = $id";
```

OR practice using database abstraction libraries.

Comment: problem solved. it gave me an idea on the WHERE clause. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You must have a *valid and matching* id(s) for the row(s) you're trying to affect. How you determine that is up to you. Then, do something like:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this on line 6

```
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE appointment SET willChangeColumn = 'newValueForThatColumn' WHERE appointmentstatusid=".$_POST['appointmentstatusid'];
```

Comment: this query will update all because not declared any condition, if you want update special rows you must declare condition with WHERE